What is the standard way to enable/install packages in rocky linux?
I want to build a package for rockylinux of a project of mine:
https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod
I was able to create packages for ubuntu, debian and fedora without much issues.... just install the packages (including the devel ones), build and that's it. Result so far:
https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod/releases/tag/v0.11
But I am scratching my head over the fact that rockylinux does not provide a lot out of the box (using rockylinux:9 docker image):
# dnf search libgit2 fuse3 glib2 cunit
No matches found.

What repos should I enable to see packages related to those search terms?

you're probably missing EPEL :)

It appears to be so. Thanks @MarcusMüller. Feel free to provide it as an answer.

If a package is available in Fedora, but not in standard Rocky/Alma/Red Hat, chances are it pays to enable the EPEL repositories; that's usually as easy as
dnf install epel-release
dnf check-update

